# Loading .npz with Python 3.5 always crashes

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

In this simple [tutorial](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~thickstn/intro.html) written in Python 2.7, they have a line loading the numpy array.

```
train_data = np.load(open('../musicnet.npz','rb'))
```

Then, they get the data by calling different keys

```
X,Y = train_data['2494']
```

Everything works well in python 2.7

Data type of `train_data` is `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile`

### My problem

However, whenever I try to do the same in Python 3.5, most of the lines work fine, except when it comes to the line of `X,Y = train_data['2494']`, it just freezes there forever. I would like to use Python 3.5 because my other projects are written in python 3.5.

How to rewrite this line so that it runs with Python 3.5?

### Error Message

I finally managed to get the error message in terminal
[image]

It freezes there because there's tons of output right after the error message, my jupyter notebook just cannot handle that much information.
[image]

### Solution

Change the encoding to 'bytes'

```
train_data = np.load('../musicnet.npz', encoding='bytes')
```

Then everything works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't need to open yourself.  Just give `load` the filename: `train_data = np.load('../musicnet.npz')`

Comment: I tried removing the `open()`, the code still freeze at `X,Y = train_data['2494']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first said things crashed, now you say it freezes when trying to access a specific  array.  `numpy` has the same syntax in 3.5 compared to 2.7.  You shouldn't have to rewrite anything.

`np.load` does have a couple of parameters that deal with differences between Py2 and Py3.  But I'm not sure these are an issue for you.

```
fix_imports : bool, optional
    Only useful when loading Python 2 generated pickled files on Python 3,
    which includes npy/npz files containing object arrays. If `fix_imports`
    is True, pickle will try to map the old Python 2 names to the new names
    used in Python 3.
encoding : str, optional
    What encoding to use when reading Python 2 strings. Only useful when
    loading Python 2 generated pickled files in Python 3, which includes
    npy/npz files containing object arrays. Values other than 'latin1',
    'ASCII', and 'bytes' are not allowed, as they can corrupt numerical
    data. Default: 'ASCII'
```

Try

```
print(list(train_data.keys()))
```

This should show the array names that were saved to the `zip` archive.  Do they match the names in the Py2 load?  Do they include the '2494' name?

A couple of things are unusual about:

```
X,Y = train_data['2494']
```

Naming an array in the zip archive by a string number, and unpacking the load into two variables.

Do you know anything about how this was `savez`?  What was saved?

Another question - are you loading this file from the same machine that Py2 worked on?  Or has the file been transferred from another machine, and possibly corrupted?

As those parameters indicate, there are differences in the `pickle` code between Py2 and Py3.  If the original save included object dtype arrays, or non-array objects, then they will be `pickled` and there might be incompatibilities in the pickle versions.

Comment: It freezes there because there's tons of output, and my jupyter notebook cannot handle it, once the memory exploded, jupyter notebook crashes. I have attached the error message in my update question.

I have checked that the `'2494'` name is included in `list(train_data.keys())`

This is a dataset for machine learning, X is the model input and Y is the label.
I am running the same code with Py2 and Py3 on the same machine. If I run with Py2, it works, if I run with Py3, there's problem. I am sure that there's no problem in the `.npz file`

Comment: The error you added points to `pickle` as I suspected.  I'd try `encoding='bytes'`. or failing that the 'latin1' alternative suggested by the `load` docs.

Comment: It works by using `train_data = np.load('../musicnet.npz', encoding='bytes')`.


But the flag `'r'` also meaning `encoding='bytes'`, isn't it? But when I try `train_data = np.load('../musicnet.npz', 'r')`, the code still crashes at `X,Y = train_data['2494']`

Comment: The encoding is a `pickle` parameter, not a file one.  `load` given just the name does open with 'rb' - that's evident from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
with np.load('../musicnet.npz') as train_data:
    X,Y = train_data['2494']
```

Comment: I tried this, it still freezes at the line `X,Y = train_data['2494']`

Comment: what is dataType of `train_data`?

Comment: When I run `type(train_data)` , it shows `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile`

Comment: @RavenCheuk, answer was updated. Please check now and confirm.

Comment: Still the same problem, freezes at `X,Y = train_data['2494']` forever.

Comment: What is length of `train_data`?  `print(len(train_data))` Is the file you want to read is updating in background?

Comment: `print(len(train_data))` shows 330, the file is static, no update to the file while the code is running

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways out in my point of view:

1. re-edit your code

   `train_data = np.load(open('../musicnet.npz','rb'))`

to

`train_data = np.load(open('../musicnet.npz','r'))`

Because the mode of `r/rb` in python2.7 / 3.5 is a difference in your situation.

2. Using the default debugger to pointing the significant error. (Usually, work on my experience)

Comment: Can you say more about how to use the default debugger? When I run the `X,Y = train_data['2494']` line, it still freeze there forever, no error message is given and no other actions can be done.